# In oracle db, Is it better practice to default data in a column or set value in insert statement?

Tags: oracle

I have a table and need to populate two columns with default data: col_1 with 1, col_2 with date. Should I let the table set these value in default, or should I set the values in INSERT statement in my application?

The reason is that in the past, the old table has defaulted value, but in one of the release, the old table was copied to a new table and the new table does not have these default value, causing a bug in my application. I want to set the value in the application itself so as to avoid this in future, but which way is the better practice?

Comment: Well I guess that's just a matter of taste...

Comment: I like to set the default to the column...as this holds everyone to the same business rule....that's just me.

Comment: @APC..Are we talking about the same thing? Integrity rules and constraints don't qualify as business rules?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a matter of opinion. But your question is worth an answer.

I think we should define DEFAULT values for columns only rarely. Good candidates are metadata columns (identity columns, created_date, created_by, etc) which applications can reasonably expect to be able to ignore. Perhaps also flag columns or status columns, when there is an obvious initial value which applies in most cases; but even for such columns I would expect application code to set explicit values.

I also think if we define a table to have DEFAULT values it should only be for mandatory (NOT NULL) columns. That constraint requires applications to accept the default or provide an explicit value.

One last point:

> the old table was copied to a new table and the new table does not have these default value

This smacks of bad practice. Tables should be created in new environments using scripts taken from a source control repository. That is the closest you'll get to a "better practice", and certainly one would would have obviated the configuration pickle you describe.

Comment: I'd add that the 12c `default on null` is an improvement on the old style `default` and should be used instead wherever possible.